# biblatex-chicago gives ibid. on new page and repeats page number

Tags: biblatex, citing, footnotes, biblatex-chicago, ibidem

I cite with biblatex-chicago and have two issues:
First, Ibid even continues on new pages like here:
[image: Ibid on new page]

Second, Ibid reprints page number after certain iterations:
[image]

My preamble for bibliography:

```
            \usepackage[backend=biber, isbn=false, useibid=true,
                pagetracker=true]{biblatex-chicago}
            \renewcommand*{\mkibid}[1]{\autocap{i}bid\adddot}
```

Would anyone know a solution for my two issues? Thank in advance!

Comment: This question provides a nice example of why it is important to provide a full compilable minimal working example... Anyway, my crystal ball tells me you are using `twoside` option (the default for, e.g., the `book` class) and when the ibids occur on a new page, it is a odd page, continuing from the facing (even) one.